# Impact of one synchronized from another synchronized method in multi-thread environment?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, wait

I am working with the synchronization threads where I have three synchronized method and each method will access by individual thread (Total 3 threads in current program )

In our program we are calling one syn method is calling another sync method, below is sample code which is inspired from real application :

```
public class ThreadTest {

    public static synchronized void suncMessage() {
        System.out.print("1");
    }

    public static synchronized void suncMessage2() {
        suncMessage();
        System.out.print("2");
    }

    public static synchronized void suncMessage3(String s) {
        System.out.print("3m" + s);
    }

    public static void main(String... at) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread t1 = new Thread() {

            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
                    suncMessage();
                }
            }
        };

        Thread t2 = new Thread() {

            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
                    suncMessage2();
                }
            }
        };

        Thread t3 = new Thread() {

            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
                    suncMessage3("3");
                }
            }
        };

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
    }
}
```

So my question is, what is impact of calling one synch. method from another synch.?? Is it good practices and how it will impact the complexity of program?

Comment: Multiple synch methods on the same object = no impact.   Multiple synch public methods on different objects = dead lock.

Comment: Yeah that's right, but what my question is if we call one synch method from another synch. method, then it will impact on performance of program or not. And it will be if some can explain it to me that, how it will impact on code complexity.

Comment: Performance is irrelevant. However there's always the danger of deadlocks. Not in simple situations of course, but as soon as it gets more complex you need to think about what you're doing.

Comment: In the posted code using a class-level lock, only 1 thread can make progress at a time.

Comment: You should always try to make your critical sections (e.g., `synchronized` methods or blocks) as small as you can possibly make them.  If you have one synchronized method calling another, that's a sign that you aren't trying very hard.

Comment: `"if we call one synch method from another synch. method"` If the synch methods are *on the same object*, there is essentially no impact (the performance hit is negligible).  If the methods on different objects (even if the same class) then there is risk of dead lock, which is a huge deal.  But there's also no real performance impact in the second case.  If methods must be synch'd, you must do so.  But if there's risk of dead lock, you must design it away.

Answer (score 1):

Nice question, but you have to try hard when you are working on this type of scenarios and the performance may effect. Because **synchronization is approx 50** time slower than normal method.

Comment: ok sure but thanks to all for the feedback will make my business logic more effective by following your guiding's